# How is MayaOnline authentication happening?

Tags: openebs

How can I login to MayaOnline and connect my clusters to it? How does the authentication workflow happen?

Answer (score 0):

At present MayaOnline supports authentication using Github credentials. If you have github account, you can sign into MayaOnline and import the clusters.